# Android 11 : How to write at 30 files per seconds on removable storage (ssd drive on usb)

Tags: android, usb, android-11, storage-access-framework, solid-state-drive

I want to save images taken from my app directly to a ssd drive (removable storage) plugged in my device.
The issue I have now, is that with Android 11, I didn't manage to get the path of this storage, and so I can't write the files...
I tried use Storage Access Framework to ask the user to specify the path directly for each images but I can't use this solution as I need to write 30 images per seconds and it kept asking the user select an action on the screen.
This application is only for internal use, so I can grant all the permission without any Google deployment politics issues.
Can anybody help me, i'm so desperate...

Comment: Use `getExternalFilesDirs()` on `Context`. If that returns 2+ elements, the second and subsequent elements are directories on removable storage where your app can write directly to the filesystem. You may still have speed issues, as 30 images/second is a fairly brisk pace. "it kept asking the user select an action on the screen" -- then you did not use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, to let the user give you access to a directory ("document tree") in which to work.

Comment: Ok thanks, will try now !

Comment: So after trying, when running `getExternalFilesDirs()`, it seems that it only shows one storage (the internal one -> 0). And for the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, even after choosing the right folder, it keeps asking me for each file I want to write on the folder...

Comment: "it keeps asking me for each file I want to write on the folder" -- you might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing what you are doing. With `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, there is a UI for requesting access to the tree, but that is it. Writing to individual documents is handled through `DocumentFile` and `ContentResolver`, not via other `Intent` actions (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) that might display a UI.

Comment: Amazing, you just saved my life here ! I confused the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` with the `DocumentFile` and `ContentResolver`... One last question before posting the answer with your solution, do you know if it is possible to ask the permission for the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` only one time and it keeps between two launch of the application ?

Comment: Call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver` when you get the `Uri` to the tree. That will give you durable access to the tree and the content that you create inside of it.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you again, now trying to find a way to keep up the 30 fps !

Comment: If you find it tell us. Easily doable on Android 10-. But i found Android 11 extremely slow on removable media. Please inform us.

Answer (score 0):

So here's my code, I can write on a folder the user choose with SAF. Still have speed issue using `DocumentFile.createFile` function.

```
package com.example.ssdwriter

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.*
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "SSDActivity"
    private val CONTENT = ByteArray(2 * 1024 * 1024)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        grantDirectoryAccess()
    }

    private fun grantDirectoryAccess() {
        val treeUri = contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions
        if (treeUri.size > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, treeUri.size.toString())
            startWriting(treeUri[0].uri)
        } else {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            var resultLauncher =
                registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        val data: Intent? = result.data
                        result.data?.data?.let {
                            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                                it,
                                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                            )
                        }
                        startWriting(result.data?.data!!)
                    }
                }
            resultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun startWriting(uri: Uri) {
        var handlerThread = HandlerThread("writer")
        handlerThread.start()
        var counter = 0
        val handler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
        val runnableCode: Runnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Writing File $counter")
                createFile(uri, counter++)
                Log.e(TAG, "File $counter written ")
                if(counter <= 150){
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 33)
                }
            }
        }
        handler.post(runnableCode)
    }

    private fun createFile(treeUri: Uri, counter: Int) {
        val dir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri)
        val file = dir!!.createFile("*/bmp", "Test$counter.bmp")

        if (file != null) {
            var outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(file.uri)
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.write(CONTENT)
                outputStream.flush()
                outputStream.close()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone got some clues to make this faster, it would be great !